# ganache-cli 127.0.0.1:8080 bad request

Tags: ganache

Alright, it looks like everything in the terminals is running well. The contract looks to be deployed successfully. It seems like there's supposed to be an API or something I can access via looking up the port that's being listened to. Ganache-cli says `Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080` but when I put this into my browser I get `40 bad request`

Comment: What command line are you using? ganache-cli is command line only it doesn't have a frontend.

Comment: I'm following [this](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask) example. testrpc is supposed to be the old version of ganache from what I can tell. Did they get rid of the front end when they moved it to ganache?

Comment: That is a very old article I'd not use that as a starting example anymore. I'd suggest to try the Pet shop tutorial at https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop. More examples at https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes.

Comment: Ahhh okay. I was able to get it to work without a front end but I'll look into these for more tutorials. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ganache-cli is hosted at port 8545. try that I am sure It will work.

Comment: I used a custom port option to change which one, but I had the same error when I put it in the browser. Does ganache automatically set up an API or is there something I'm supposed to implement that I've neglected?